# AndroidThings TimeZone for a Date object is GMT+00

Tags: datetime, android-things

I am writing an android things app (dev preview 3) for the raspberry pi 3.

I am connecting the app to a wifi network and  when I do a `new Date()` the time is correct (offset by the timezone - minutes/seconds correct) except for the timeZone which is being set to `GMT+00:00`  (i.e., timezone 0).

I want to deploy the device into households and need to automatically set their timezone,  since I'm connecting to their wifi network, I assume the I should be able to know their timezone.   Is this do able or is this just a problem with preview 3 and will be corrected in future releases of `Android` things?

Comment: Please file a bug report at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192720&template=847005

Comment: For your particular problem you can probably get a guesstimate from the IP address and being able to geolocate your device. I'm also interested in this solution, with an added twist of choosing language and defaults for 12 AM/PM or 24 hour clock. I guess these should start being addressed when they launch the integration with Weave?

Comment: Using Dev preview 5.1 and have the same problem still.

Comment: Dev preview 6.0 now lets you set the timezone, but it's not automatic.

https://developer.android.com/things/reference/com/google/android/things/device/TimeManager.html

As @fabio mentioned, you could probably guess the timezone based on IP geolocation.